# Oracle SQL Division by set with unknown # of elements

Tags: sql, oracle, division

I have looked around all over the place, but I can not seem to find an answer to this question.

I am working on a database project. I have a table that contains cars and their colors.

It has a structure as such:

```
owner_id || car_make || car_color
   001   ||   ford   ||     red
   001   ||   ford   ||     blue
   002   ||   chevy  ||     red
   002   ||   Telsa  ||     blue
   002   ||   ford   ||     green
   003   ||   chevy  ||     red
   004   ||   chevy  ||     red
   004   ||   Telsa  ||     blue
   005   ||   ford   ||     red
   005   ||   ford   ||     blue
```

What I want to be able to do is to display the owner_id list of all the owners who own cars the same color and make as another owner. 
For example if I select all the cars owned by owner 001 I get

```
owner_id || car_make || car_color
   001   ||   ford   ||     red
   001   ||   ford   ||     blue
```

What SQL could I use to get the list of user_ids of other owners who own both a red ford and a blue ford?

I would want to get 005 returned, because owner 005 owns both a red ford and a blue ford, same as owner 001

I know SQL does not support division as such, and I have tried other methods such as minus and not exists, but I must be doing them incorrectly, because I get nothing but errors, or simply incorrect results.

Again, apologies if this has been answered already, and for my poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work - it creates a list of owner 001 make and color, joins all the other owners against the list, and only includes those owners who match for all of owner 001's cars:

```
WITH
  Owner001_Cars AS (
    SELECT car_make, car_color
    FROM myTable
    WHERE owner_id = '001')
SELECT owner_id
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN Owner001_Cars USING (car_make, car_color)
WHERE owner_id <> '001'
GROUP BY owner_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Owner001_Cars)
```

Comment: @KevinDustie you would have to run that for every single owner

Answer (score 1):

This will show all instances where someone owns cars of a make and color which are all identical to all the cars owned by at least one other owner.

```
select *
  from tbl x
 where not exists (select 1
          from tbl y
         where y.car_make <> x.car_make
           and y.car_color <> x.car_color
           and y.owner_id <> x.owner_id)
```

Comment: apologies, I should have been more clear. I want to return instances where an owner owns ALL the same car make/color combinations as another owner

so in my example, the query I want would return 005, because owner 005 also owns both a red ford and a blue ford, same as user 1

Comment: @KevinDustie see my new query in the edit. It should do that. The cars of each owner will all be aggregated into one set in the 2nd column. Only sets of cars where there are 2+ owners get returned.

Comment: @KevinDustie I just did a 2nd edit, try this one. It should run faster than the listagg idea.